# display related data from Community user/Contact in Site.com

Tags: site.com

I am trying to create a splash page for my Customer Community using Site.com. I've got most of it set up and it looks fine. I wanted to add a section that shows data from a Related object (Affiliation) that is linked to Contact records. I'd like the data to only display the related Affiliation records based on the Contact of the logged in user. I have a data connection element, and I can filter it by Logged In user, but I can't figure out how to link that to the Contact record of the user to then filter/display only custom objects related to the Contact. What am I missing?

Comment: It turned out that I had it set correctly, I just had to test as a logged in user rather than as the administrator (which showed all). Once I logged in as one person everything filtered appropriately.

Comment: For others who might be interested, I created nested repeater elements. The first repeater was the User object and filtered by current User. Then my next object was able to be filtered by Contact ID from the parent repeater.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that Community users are not Contacts, they're Portal Users. You'll need to use their Portal UserId to obtain their ContactID.